# confused by different ADK libraries

Tags: arduino, adk

I am trying to setup Arduino IDE v 1.0.1 to work with Ardunio mega ADK , I setup everything but the problem that there are many adk libraries around specifically there are 
**adk_release_20120606** which can be downloaded from android developer website
http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk.html
and there are **ArduinoADK-beta-001** which can be downloaded from ardunio labs http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/AccessoryMode .

according to labs.ardunio.cc **ArduinoADK-beta-001** is the newer version .

> If you have any of the following Arduino libraries installed you will need to remove them:
>   AndroidAccessory
>   USB_Host_Shield (both version 1.x and 2.x)
>   The new UsbHost library cannot co-exist with the older AndroidAccessory library nor any version of the USB_Host_Shield library.

but the problem is that all existed sketches on the web uses the old one, for example the **poweron()** methd is not existed in the  **ArduinoADK-beta-001** and instead you should use **begin()** .

the other thing is read() method in the older library its can take 3 arguments but in the newer one its has no argument .

i've opened the **AndroidAccessory.h** in both libraries and i found that in  **ArduinoADK-beta-00** contain all the methods in the older one but they are set to private so they can't be used , here is what inside the header file:

```
#ifndef __AndroidAccessory_h__
#define __AndroidAccessory_h__

#include "UsbHost.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Stream.h"

#define DATA_BUFFER_SIZE 64

class AndroidAccessory : public Stream {
private:
const char *manufacturer;
const char *model;
const char *description;
const char *version;
const char *uri;
const char *serial;

MAX3421E max;
UsbHost usb;
bool connected;
uint8_t in;
uint8_t out;

EP_RECORD epRecord[8];

// TODO: Reuse `descBuff` after connection and/or stream descriptor?
uint8_t descBuff[256];

byte dataBuff[DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
unsigned int numBytesInDataBuff;
unsigned int nextByteInDataBuffOffset;

bool isAccessoryDevice(USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *desc)
{
    return desc->idVendor == 0x18d1 &&
        (desc->idProduct == 0x2D00 || desc->idProduct == 0x2D01);
}

int getProtocol(byte addr);
void sendString(byte addr, int index, const char *str);
bool switchDevice(byte addr);
bool findEndpoints(byte addr, EP_RECORD *inEp, EP_RECORD *outEp);
bool configureAndroid(void);

bool dataBufferIsEmpty();
void refillDataBuffer();

// Private because it bypasses the data buffer.
int read(void *buff, int len, unsigned int nakLimit = USB_NAK_NOWAIT);

void powerOn(void);

public:
AndroidAccessory(const char* manufacturer,
                 const char* model,
                 const char* description = "An Arduino-based Android accessory",
                 const char* version = "1.0",6
                 const char* uri = "http://labs.arduino.cc/ADK/Index",
                 const char* serial = "00000000");

boolean begin(void);

void refresh(void);

bool isConnected(void);
virtual size_t write(uint8_t *buff, size_t len);

virtual int available(void);
virtual int peek(void);
virtual int read(void);

virtual void flush();
virtual size_t write(uint8_t);

using Print::write; // pull in write(str) and write(buf, size) from Print
};

#endif /* __AndroidAccessory_h__ */
```

so as we can see the `poweron()` method is still exsisted but its private and the `read()` is declared twice one in the private section like this:

```
 int read(void *buff, int len, unsigned int nakLimit = USB_NAK_NOWAIT);
```

and the other in public section like this

```
 virtual int read(void);
```

so the question, how could I use the `read()` function? And where the data should be stored when they received from the android device?